# Show placeholder when navigating through suggestions in an AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-desktop

Is it possible to show the placeholder (I mean, not showing any selected item in the textbox) when the user is navigating through the AutoSuggestBox suggestions list? It would be a similar function as the Windows 10 weather app that when user is selecting one item from the search box list it shows the placeholder in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Show placeholder when navigating through suggestions in an AutoSuggestBox

Sure, [`AutoSuggestBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox) contains [`PlaceholderText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.placeholdertext) property, you could set it value or bind value with c.

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="string"/>
```

> when user is selecting one item from the search box list it shows the placeholder in the textbox

AutoSuggestBox will automatically fill `TextBox` content ([`UpdateTextOnSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.updatetextonselect)) when you select the option in suggestion list, but it is not `PlaceholderText`. if you do want to change `PlaceholderText` at this moment, you could set UpdateTextOnSelect as `False` and detect AutoSuggestBox `SuggestionChosen` event then set `PlaceholderText` there.

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.SelectedItem is string item)
    {
        sender.Text = string.Empty;
        sender.PlaceholderText = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that he wants the placeholder text to be changed even when the pointer simply hovers on some suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for